# Synergy Keyboard and Mouse: Client or Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, client, synergy

I'm doing a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 install on a Lenovo ThinkServer. This is going to be on the same worksurface as a HP Win 7 Laptop  with 8GB RAM (on a dock) with the laptop screen, an attached screen, and another screen for the ThinkServer. I'd love to use Synergy to share a mouse and keyboard, and have a registered account with them.

Now, assuming I'll have no trouble installing it (big if?), my question is which to make the server and which the client? If it helps, the Windows machine has my email, web and light data work, the Lenovo Ubuntu install will be the data wrangling workhorse. My instinct says to make Lenovo the server, since the laptop has its built-in keyboard.

Any suggestions?

---

Oh, one complication might be that I'm planning to also link them remotely to another machine using TeamViewer. I've noticed strange behavior in the past using Synergy + Teamviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, assuming I'll have no trouble installing it (big if?),

It took me something like 10 minutes connecting 2 Ubuntu desktops and a Windows 7 desktop with an Ubuntu VM in it at work.

1 thing you must make sure: use the SAME version on all machines.

> my question is which to make the server and which the client? ... If it helps, the Windows machine has my email, web and light data work, the Lenovo Ubuntu install will be the data wrangling workhorse. My instinct says to make Lenovo the server, since the laptop has its built-in keyboard.

It really does not matter. I would take the one that you use the most since if you want to tinker with it you will need that machine. The clients just need the software and an  IP adres to probe. The server also needs a lay-out (on where you can reach the screens).

Regarding the keyboard: I have an extra keyboard and screen and all the notebooks are closed.

Comment: The reason I'm  asking is because I've had similar installations showing significant lag (seconds) despite using a multi Gb/s internet.

Comment: What's internet got to do with it? Your network is what needs to be good (ie. system1<->router<->system2). If it lags check your router log for problems ;)

Comment: Good point, meraki'd it and looks like I'm too close to the wifi access point. Will try a switch. Thanks!

Comment: if in trouble feel free to drop a message in AU chat.

Comment: Thanks, a.t.m. still stuck in the eternal ubuntu install screen.